# Error with asp.net mvc application in monodevelop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

I just installed monodevelop.
I want to start with asp.net mvc using mono, but I cant'n make it work. I start a new ASP.NET mvc project, and I want to compile the default generated code, but I get an error on the line:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

saying

```
The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
```

Note:

I have Monodevelop in spanish, the actual error I get is

```
El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'Mvc' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'System.Web' (;falta una referencia de ensamblado?)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does your solution reference `System.Web.Mvc`? I'm on OSX using MDK 2.10.9, MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4 and it works ootb with the default template.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `using` directive you have to add a reference to the actual .dll containing the code you want to use.

To achieve that in monodevelop you have to go to *References* in the Solution pane and select *Edit References*. A new dialog will popup where you should be able to add a reference to `System.Web.Mvc`.